# How do I change the color of a single rectangle in a grid?

Tags: python, grid, pygame

I've already programmed a grid, but now I want to change the color of a single rectangle in the grid.

```
x = 5
y = 5

height = 30
width = 50
size = 20
color = (255,255,255)
new_color = (255,255,0)

screen.fill((0,0,0))

def draw_grid():
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x * (size + 1),y * (size + 1),size,size)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,rect)
            x += 20
            rects.append((rect,color))
        y += 20

rects = []
colored_rects = []

while 1:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    draw_grid()

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for i,(rect,color) in enumerate(rects):
            if rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                rects[i] = (rect,new_color)
                colored_rects.append((rect,new_color))


    for rect,color in rects:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,rect)
    for rect,new_color in colored_rects:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,new_color,rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick()
```

Now I only want to change one rectangle when I click on it, but later they must change automatically (for example when there are three rectangles touching in the same color, they all must become white). I've updated a little bit, but there are still some problems. For example: You have to click on the rectangle till it changes color, and it takes to much time te change color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to store the rects together with their color in tuples. If the mouse button is pressed, you iterate over the `rectangles` list, if a rectangle collides with the mouse, you create a tuple with the rect and the new color and replace the tuple at the current index.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()

    height = 30
    width = 50
    size = 20
    color = (255, 255, 255)
    new_color = (255, 255, 0)

    rectangles = []
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            rect = pg.Rect(x * (size+1), y * (size+1), size, size)
            # The grid will be a list of (rect, color) tuples.
            rectangles.append((rect, color))

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            mouse_pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            # Enumerate creates tuples of a number (the index)
            # and the rect-color tuple, so it looks like:
            # (0, (<rect(0, 0, 20, 20)>, (255, 255, 255)))
            # You can unpack them directly in the head of the loop.
            for index, (rect, color) in enumerate(rectangles):
                if rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    # Create a tuple with the new color and assign it.
                    rectangles[index] = (rect, new_color)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))

        # Now draw the rects. You can unpack the tuples
        # again directly in the head of the for loop.
        for rect, color in rectangles:
            pg.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: I've tried this code, it works but if I click on a rectangle it changes color for only a second or less. And it doesn't work always.

Comment: Add your updated code to your post and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I've just udpated it

Comment: The first problem that I see is that you're appending new (rect, color) tuples to the `rects` list all the time in the `draw_grid` function. Try to `print(len(rects))` in your while loop to see how it grows. You'll finally run out of memory if you keep doing this. Instead of appending rects you should just draw them and if the user clicks on a rect, update the (rect, color) tuple at the specific index.

Comment: Take another look at my example. I first create the `rectangles` list and then append the (rect, color) tuples outside of the while loop. Inside of the `while` loop I just iterate over the `rectangles` list to draw the rects with their respective color, I **don't append new tuples**. To update the color of a rect, I iterate over the enumerated tuples and, if the mouse collided with one of them, I only change the tuple in the list at the current index, nothing else.

Comment: That also means you can remove the `colored_rects` list. --- BTW, drawing so many rects is not good for the performance. It would be better to use only one big background surface and blit it once each frame, but I'm not sure how well that would work with a grid based game.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!